# How insert data from a temporary table into partitioned table in oracle/sql using merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, temp-tables, data-partitioning

I have to write a merge statement to insert data from temporary table to a partitioned table and i'm getting below error:-

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition

1. I have to do it session wise and as a result, have to use a temporary table which can not be partitioned.

Comment: What is your insert statement and what is the table definition?

Comment: I think a temporary table can be partitioned

Comment: The problem is that you have a value in the data in your temporary table which does not have anyplace to be put in your permanent partitioned table. It doesn't matter that the temporary table is or is not partitioned, nor does it matter that you're using a `MERGE` or an `INSERT` statement. You need to figure out which value in the temp table field which is used as the partitioning key does not have a corresponding partition in the partitioned table. We'd need to see every row in your temp table, and all the partitions defined on your partitioned table to be able to help you with this.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have searched it and it seems that we can't

Answer (score 0):

if your inserts datasets into the partioned table, oracle want to place it
into the correct partionen. You must create for the complete period of time 
partitions like in example for MONTHY partition:

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD 
PARTITION sales_q1_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-APR-2007','dd-MON-yyyy')),
PARTITION sales_q2_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JUL-2007','dd-MON-yyyy')),
PARTITION sales_q3_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-OCT-2007','dd-MON-yyyy')),
PARTITION sales_q4_2007 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008','dd-MON-yyyy'))
;
```

If you have done this, you can insert the data ass needed.
Good luck,

Comment: For such setup you better use `INTERVAL` partitions, then Oracle creates the partitions automatically.